# How to show that $\int x e^{-x^2/2} dx = -e^{-x^2/2} + c$?

Tags: calculus, integration, integration-by-parts

> I wish to show that
>
> $\int x e^{-x^2/2} dx = -e^{-x^2/2} + c$

I tried using integration by parts

Consider $\int u dv = vu - \int v du$

Let $dv = xdx, u = e^{-x^2/2}$

Then $\int x e^{-x^2/2} dx = x^2/2 * e^{-x^2/2} + \int x^2/2 * xe^{-x^2/2} dx$

This gets me no where close to my desired solution

Can anyone help?

Comment: well generally $\int f'=f$ so what about calculating $f'$ for $f(x)=-e^{-x^2/2}$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go by substitution. Put $\dfrac{x^2}{2} = t$

$$\therefore x dx = dt$$

$$\int x e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} dx = \int e^{-t} dt = -e^{-t} + c$$

On resubstituting, we get $\int x e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} dx = -e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} + c$

Answer (score 2):

Don't use integration by parts. This is just a u-substitution. Sub $u = x^2/2$ so that $du = xdx$ is right there.

Comment: Thanks, it has been a few years since I did calculus!

Comment: @StackexchangeHouseNinja No problem. Don't sleep on zwim's comment. If you know or suspect you know the answer to an indefinite integral, you can always *prove* it's the answer by differentiating (which, as you'll probably recall, is generally easier than integrating). However that would not be useful if you didn't already know the answer.